# How to substract values off two different tables in SQL reporting Builder

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am having trouble subtracting these two values off my table since I am actually lost on subtraction clause because I have been trying to subtract the values with no success, Here is my query :

```
 SELECT
 HQCO.HQCo,
 HQCO.Name Name1,
 JCJP.Contract,
 JCJP.Item It1,
 JCJP.Phase ph1,
 JCCP.CostType,
 JCCI.Item It2,
 JCCI.Description Desc1,
 JCCP.Phase ph2,
 JCJP.Description Desc2,
 JCCT.Description Desc3,
 JCCH.UM,
 JCCP.CurrEstUnits,
 JCCP.CurrEstCost,
 JCCP.ActualUnits,
 JCCP.ActualCost,
 JCCM.Description Desc4,
 JCJP.JCCo,
 JCCP.ProjCost,
 JCCP.RemainCmtdCost,
 JCCP.ProjPlug,
 JCCP.Mth,
 JCCI.BilledAmt BilledAmt1,
 JCCM.BilledAmt BilledAmt2,

 JCCM.udGEACrev,
 JCCP.Job,
 JCCM.Department,
 JCJM.ProjectMgr,
 JCMP.Name Name2

 FROM

     Viewpoint.dbo.JCCP  
       INNER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.HQCO ON JCCP.JCCo = HQCO.HQCo
       INNER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCCT ON JCCP.PhaseGroup = JCCT.PhaseGroup 
 AND JCCP.CostType = JCCT.CostType
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCCH ON JCCP.JCCo = JCCH.JCCo AND 
 JCCP.Job = JCCH.Job  
       AND JCCP.PhaseGroup = JCCH.PhaseGroup AND JCCP.Phase = JCCH.Phase  
 AND JCCP.CostType = JCCH.CostType
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCJP ON JCCP.JCCo = JCJP.JCCo AND 
 JCCP.Job = JCJP.Job 
       AND JCCP.PhaseGroup = JCJP.PhaseGroup AND JCCP.Phase  = JCJP.Phase 
 AND JCJP.JCCo = 1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCCI ON JCJP.JCCo = JCCI.JCCo AND 
 JCJP.Contract = JCCI.Contract AND JCJP.Item  = JCCI.Item 
       INNER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCCM ON JCCI.JCCo = JCCM.JCCo AND 
 JCCI.Contract = JCCM.Contract 
       INNER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCJM ON JCCM.JCCo = JCJM.JCCo AND 
 JCCM.Contract = JCJM.Job 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCMP ON JCJM.JCCo = JCMP.JCCo AND 
 JCJM.ProjectMgr = JCMP.ProjectMgr


 WHERE
    JCCP.Mth < {ts '2017-06-02 00:00:00'} 
    AND JCJM.ProjectMgr = 12
    AND JCCM.Department = '10' 
 ORDER BY JCJP.Contract, JCJP.Item, JCJP.Phase, JCCP.CostType
```

This is the table :
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1kUn.png)

What I am trying to do is subtract the Sum of the actual cost from the Billed Amount 2. thanks in advance.

Comment: what are the data types of actual cost and billed amount2?

Comment: @MarkD they are numeric values (0-9) with decimals (Floats if they were in java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as they are both numeric you should just be able to minus them

```
SELECT
 HQCO.HQCo,
 HQCO.Name Name1,
 JCJP.Contract,
 JCJP.Item It1,
 JCJP.Phase ph1,
 JCCP.CostType,
 JCCI.Item It2,
 JCCI.Description Desc1,
 JCCP.Phase ph2,
 JCJP.Description Desc2,
 JCCT.Description Desc3,
 JCCH.UM,
 JCCP.CurrEstUnits,
 JCCP.CurrEstCost,
 JCCP.ActualUnits,
 JCCP.ActualCost,
 JCCM.Description Desc4,
 JCJP.JCCo,
 JCCP.ProjCost,
 JCCP.RemainCmtdCost,
 JCCP.ProjPlug,
 JCCP.Mth,
 JCCI.BilledAmt BilledAmt1,
 JCCM.BilledAmt BilledAmt2,
 JCCM.BilledAmt - JCCP.ActualCost As BilledCostDifference,
 JCCM.udGEACrev,
 JCCP.Job,
 JCCM.Department,
 JCJM.ProjectMgr,
 JCMP.Name Name2

 FROM

     Viewpoint.dbo.JCCP  
       INNER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.HQCO ON JCCP.JCCo = HQCO.HQCo
       INNER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCCT ON JCCP.PhaseGroup = JCCT.PhaseGroup 
 AND JCCP.CostType = JCCT.CostType
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCCH ON JCCP.JCCo = JCCH.JCCo AND 
 JCCP.Job = JCCH.Job  
       AND JCCP.PhaseGroup = JCCH.PhaseGroup AND JCCP.Phase = JCCH.Phase  
 AND JCCP.CostType = JCCH.CostType
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCJP ON JCCP.JCCo = JCJP.JCCo AND 
 JCCP.Job = JCJP.Job 
       AND JCCP.PhaseGroup = JCJP.PhaseGroup AND JCCP.Phase  = JCJP.Phase 
 AND JCJP.JCCo = 1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCCI ON JCJP.JCCo = JCCI.JCCo AND 
 JCJP.Contract = JCCI.Contract AND JCJP.Item  = JCCI.Item 
       INNER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCCM ON JCCI.JCCo = JCCM.JCCo AND 
 JCCI.Contract = JCCM.Contract 
       INNER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCJM ON JCCM.JCCo = JCJM.JCCo AND 
 JCCM.Contract = JCJM.Job 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCMP ON JCJM.JCCo = JCMP.JCCo AND 
 JCJM.ProjectMgr = JCMP.ProjectMgr


 WHERE
    JCCP.Mth < {ts '2017-06-02 00:00:00'} 
    AND JCJM.ProjectMgr = 12
    AND JCCM.Department = '10' 
 ORDER BY JCJP.Contract, JCJP.Item, JCJP.Phase, JCCP.CostType
```